# ANY edit in this threejs sample build ends up with white screen

Tags: build, three.js

I was given this sample build project to be able to play around with [threejs](https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm) since I was having trouble making the app work as a beginner. I wanted to test if I could edit the build project, so I decided to add another cube, and reposition it anywhere along the x axis. However, I noticed that I just keep getting a white screen for an unknown reason.

main.js(adding a cube)

```
import {
    BoxBufferGeometry,
    Mesh,
    MeshBasicMaterial,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    Scene,
    WebGLRenderer
} from 'three';

import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

let camera, scene, renderer;

class App {

    init() {

        camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
        camera.position.z = 400;

        scene = new Scene();

        const geometry = new BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
        const material = new MeshBasicMaterial();

        const mesh = new Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add(mesh);

        const geometry2 = new BoxBufferGeometry(200, 200, 200);
        const material2 = new MeshBasicMaterial();
        const mesh2 = Mesh(geometry2, material2);
        mesh2.position.y = -3;
        scene.add(mesh2);

        renderer = new WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

        animate();

    }

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

export { App }
```

Correct me if what I did was wrong, but I ran the following to test out the App.
`npm install` for the npm modules.
`npm run build` to update the build.js

I checked the console and the following error was shown:
[image: Browser Console]

I also tried just changing the material of the cube using the code below.

main.js (changing material)

```
import {
    BoxBufferGeometry,
    Mesh,
    MeshLambertMaterial,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    Scene,
    WebGLRenderer
} from 'three';

import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

let camera, scene, renderer;

class App {

    init() {

        camera = new PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
        camera.position.z = 400;

        scene = new Scene();

        const geometry = new BoxBufferGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
        const material = new MeshLambertMaterial();

        const mesh = new Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add(mesh);


        renderer = new WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

        animate();

    }

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

export { App }
```

This resulted in just a black screen. I could not even access the console to check the error since nothing shows up when I right click on the screen.

Is there something wrong with how I build the project after editing?

Comment: In the second snippet, where you use MeshLambertMaterial, the reason you've got black screen can be that you don't have any light source in your scene, as the material is affected by light.

Comment: @prisoner849 this helped! You can add this as a solution